# Typescript client side socket not connecting with server

Tags: node.js, sockets, typescript

I am attempting to recreate [this](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/) tutorial using typescript, routing, and jade. My code compiles and runs as expected, the jade file is served correctly, but there doesn't seem to be a connection between the client side socket and server side socket. For reference, the code from the tutorial is set like this:

Javascript file:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
});
```

html file:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io();
</script>
```

And mine looks like this:

Server side:

```
import io = require('socket.io');
var server: SocketIO.Server = io();

server.on('connection', function(socket){
console.log('A user connected');
});
```

Client side:

```
declare var io: SocketIOClientStatic;
var socket = io();
```

I've moved the relevant server and client side code to different locations and tried a few different things. I've used regular javascript (exactly like the tutorial) for the client side, I've moved the script into the jade file, and I've moved the server side script around app.ts and index.ts (which app.ts routes to). I haven't been able to get the logged message from a connection event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Javascript (a little bit rewritten):

```
var io = require('socket.io');
var server = io(http);

server.on(...);
```

Your Typescript:

```
import io = require('socket.io');
var server: SocketIO.Server = io();
                                ^^ where is `http`?
server.on(...)
```

Comment: I've added http to the parameters but the problem hasn't changed.

Comment: I used  `import http = require("http");` and that looks like my only other line with `http`. Am I missing another initialization step?

Comment: @NicolasPeckman yes, in the tutorial you're referring to `http` is initialized as `var http = require('http').Server(app)`, and also (later on) the server is started using `http.listen(3000)`. Without both steps, you don't have a functioning HTTP server.

Comment: In case anyone else has these problems, the test file in the socket.io module in Definitely Typed has the layout of the solution. It's a little different from the javascript. Thanks for the help @robertklep